# Get address from co-ordinates using OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geolocation, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I'm looking for a solution which gives an address based on co-ordinates (Latitude & Longitude) which I got from html5 geolocation api. I'm using OpenStreetMap.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed, and I'm glad it's still viewable, because this question and its answer were valuable to me.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I'm guessing it's because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  However, I think just because they *tend* to, doesn't mean they *will* - this question is a perfect example.  It seems like Nominatim has become pretty much the de facto choice for solving this problem over the last few years, such that there's not tons of room for spammy opinion here.

Comment: It might be a better fit for gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No. Its for stackoverflow, because it is meant for programming

Answer (score 60):

There are multiple reverse geocoding APIs available for OpenStreetMap (since the data is open-source, anyone can build one). The two that I would recommend you investigate further are:

1. Nominatim, run by a member of the OSM community as a volunteer project. [Reverse Geocoding documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup)
2. CloudMade Geocoding, run as a commercial service. [Reverse Geocoding documentation](http://developers.cloudmade.com/documentation/geocoding/index.html) (at the bottom)

Of the two, I would recommend Nominatim. If you are building a large service and are generating lots of requests, you can even run your own copies of nominatim on your own servers.

Comment: i agree with @gravitystorm - cloudmade is a private company whose founder went to Bing after years of massive financial losses.  future of cloudmade is uncertain.  on the other hand, nominatim is a public project/tool .

Comment: API Documentation Link: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/

Comment: @DhruvangGajjar it all appears to be deprecated tho?

Comment: @oldboy endpoints with `.php` are deprecated. e.g. `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=<value>&lon=<value>&<params>
` will be working.

`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.

Comment: @DhruvangGajjar ahhh that makes sense. i had figured out in the meantime and was wondering why it was still working haha