# Java Swing GoogleMaps geoposition from zip code

Tags: java, swing, geolocation, google-maps

I found the JXMapKit from SwingLabs and think I am going to use it. My problem now is that I have data referencing the point via the zip code (I don't need more accurat). I know that with the JavaScript API from Google it is possible to find out the geoposition from an address... My question now is: does this work with Java Swing?

Thanks for advise!

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Geocoder](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.0/index.html) class in [gwt-google-apis](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/).

Answer (score 0):

Google's license does not allow using Google Maps from the applications. Take a look at http://www.openstreetmap.org/ instead - it can be easily used from JXMapKit

As far as geolocation goes take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961124/reverse-geo-location-using-openstreetmap)