# Alternative to Google's Reverse Geocoding

Tags: javascript, service, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am looking for an **alternative** to Google's reverse geocoding service.

In short, I want a user to click on a map and pre-fill a form with an address for a particular latitude and longitude. Similary to this this [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).

**EDIT**

I am using OpenStreetMaps and according to Google's terms I am not allowed to user their geocoding services without displaying them on Google Maps.

Comment: Can you clarify why Google's service won't work for you? It's hard for people to make good recommendations without knowing what your actual requirements are.

Comment: I am not allowed to use Google's geocoding services without displaying them on their maps. I use OpenStreetMaps - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: Actually quite interesting question, I would also like to know what other services provide similar features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of geolocation APIs out there. If you need **lat/long** -> **geolocation info** (such as city, country ...) correspondence you should look at the Yahoo PlaceFinder API which implements an API call returning informations based on a lat/lon pair (http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/).

However most of those APIs are free but limited by the number of API call.

What you can also do is using the IP address of a user to locate him, it will work in most cases since users using proxys or VPNs are few. Then you will be able to use a free service such as http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php or http://www.iplocationtools.com/api.html to make a correspondence between the *IP address* and the *geolocation infos*. There are even free databases you can easily find making this correspondence if you don't want to rely on third-party APIs.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961124/reverse-geo-location-using-openstreetmap) is similar.

It recommends [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup), a service run by an OSM volunteer (and if you have heavy load, you can download the relevant parts of the OSM database and run your own local instance).